# vba save excel file as?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save an excel file using vba.
Here is my code:

```
Sub Save()
With ActiveWorkbook
 On Error GoTo message
.SaveAs "G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\6. Themes and Seasonal\Christmas\2017\Volume Planning\Volume overviews\SOSP\Ambient Volumes\#" & Range(C5).Value & " - " & Range(C6).Value & ".xls", FileFormat:=56
message:
MsgBox "There is an error"
End With
End Sub
```

For some reason the code won't save the file and the code defaults to error. Please can someone show me what im doing wrong?

EDIT:

The actual excel error is method range of object global failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your ranges with `"` and add an `Exit Sub` to prevent `message:` being called to display the msgbox when not needed.

```
Sub Save()
     With ActiveWorkbook
         On Error GoTo message
         .SaveAs "G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\6. Themes and Seasonal\Christmas\2017\Volume Planning\Volume overviews\SOSP\Ambient Volumes\#" & Range("C5").Value & " - " & Range("C6").Value & ".xls", FileFormat:=56
         Exit Sub
         message:
         MsgBox "There is an error"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by that you wrote c5 instead of "c5", so it is looking for a range named by the value of c5, which is empty, and there is no Range, called empty.
Try this one:

```
Sub Save()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\6. Themes and Seasonal\Christmas\2017\Volume Planning\Volume overviews\SOSP\Ambient Volumes\#" & Range("C5").Value & " - " & Range("C6").Value & ".xls", FileFormat:=56
End Sub
```

Moreover, you don't need complicated error handling here because the default behavior is the same as you asked for: a message box with some description. So I removed it, too. If you want to do something else to handle the error then, however, you should write Exit Sub before the label of the error handler, otherwise it will show the error message even if it succeeds. And you should also restore error handling, like this:

```
Sub Save()
    On Error GoTo message
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\6. Themes and Seasonal\Christmas\2017\Volume Planning\Volume overviews\SOSP\Ambient Volumes\#" & Range("C5").Value & " - " & Range("C6").Value & ".xls", FileFormat:=56
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
message:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "There is an error"
End Sub
```

Comment: @z32a7ul can the workbook be saved as copy? With the method i am using it renames the active workbook as the new filename, i do not want this?

Comment: @z32a7ul if i use SaveCopyAs it tells me wrong number of arguements error

Comment: SaveCopyAs does not accept the FileFormat parameter (since it will be the exact copy of the current workbook and its format is already known), so remove that one.